# C#: How to split a string with a changing prefix

Tags: c#, .net, split

Hello I looked at several post about this topics but no answer could help me.

I extract data about various machines which look like this:

```
"time, M1.A, M1.B, M1.C, M2.A, M2.B, M2.C, M3.A, M3.B, M3.C"
```

M1 is the prefix which specifies which machine. A,B,C are attributes of this machine like temperature, pressure, etc.

The output should then look like this:

```
{{"time", "M1.A", "M1.B", "M1.C"}, {"time", "M2.A",....}}
```

I know that I could possibly split at "," and then create the list but I was wondering if there is another way to detect if the prefix changed.

Comment: did you tried to use [Regex.Match Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_) ?

Comment: Or just split on comma, then use LINQ to group by the first two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(myList, @"M(?<digit>\d+)\..") //find all M1.A etc
    .Cast<Match>() //convert the resulting list to an enumerable of Match
    .GroupBy(m => m.Groups["digit"].Value) //find the groups with the same digits
    .Select(g => new[] { "time" }.Union(g.Select(m => m.Value)).ToArray());
    //combine the groups into arrays beginning with "time"
```

Comment: Great, its not specifically for me, but for others that might visit the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You mention "the output should then look like this...", but then you mention a list, so I'm going to assume that you mean to make the original string into a list of lists of strings.

```
List<string> split = new List<string>(s.Split(','));
string first = split[0];
split.RemoveAt(0);
List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var dist in split.Select(o => o.Split('.')[0]).Distinct())
{
    List<string> temp = new List<string> {first};
    temp.AddRange(split.Where(o => o.StartsWith(dist)));
    result.Add(temp);
}
```

This does the original split, removes the first value (you didn't really specify that, I assumed), then loops around each machine.  The machines are created by splitting each value further by '.' and making a distinct list.  It then selects all values in the list that start with the machine and adds them with the first value to the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex I created a dictionary :

```
           string input = "time, M1.A, M1.B, M1.C, M2.A, M2.B, M2.C, M3.A, M3.B, M3.C";
            string pattern1 = @"^(?'name'[^,]*),(?'machines'.*)";
            Match match1 = Regex.Match(input, pattern1);
            string name = match1.Groups["name"].Value;
            string machines = match1.Groups["machines"].Value.Trim();

            string pattern2 = @"\s*(?'machine'[^.]*).(?'attribute'\w+)(,|$)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(machines, pattern2);

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["machine"].Value, y => y.Groups["attribute"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some quick example for you. I think is better to parse it by you own way and have string structure of your Machine-Attribute pair.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string inputString = "time, M1.A, M1.B, M1.C, M2.A, M2.B, M2.C, M3.A, M3.B, M3.C";

            string[] attrList = inputString.Split(',');

            // 1. Get all machines with attributes
            List<MachineAttribute> MachineAttributeList = new List<MachineAttribute>();
            for (int i = 1; i < attrList.Length; i++) {
                MachineAttributeList.Add(new MachineAttribute(attrList[i]));
            }

            // 2. For each machine create 
            foreach (var machine in MachineAttributeList.Select(x=>x.Machine).Distinct()) {
                Console.Write(attrList[0]);
                foreach (var attribute in MachineAttributeList.Where(x=>x.Machine == machine)) {
                    Console.Write(attribute + ",");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class MachineAttribute {
        public string Machine { get; }

        public string Attribute { get; }

        public MachineAttribute(string inputData) {
            var array = inputData.Split('.');
            if (array.Length > 0) Machine = array[0];
            if (array.Length > 1) Attribute = array[1];
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return Machine + "." + Attribute;
        }
    }
}
```